# XeTeX \color runaway argument

Tags: listings, color

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper] {article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\setmainfont[BoldFont=黑体]{宋体}
%\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
%\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt minus 0.1pt
%\linespread{1.5}
\lstset{
numbers = left,
framexleftmargin=10mm,
frame=none,
backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{245,245,244},
keywordstyle=\bf\color{blue},
identifierstyle=\bf,
numberstyle=\color[RGB]{0,192,192},
commentstyle=\it\color[RGB]{0,96,96},
stringstyle=\rmfamily\s1shape\color[RGB]{128,0,0},

showstringspaces=true
}
\begin {document}
\title{实验课}
\author{ coolwind}
\maketitle
\paragraph{}
你好，世界！

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("Hello world!\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j ++)
{
int tmp = i + j;
}
}
return 0;
}

\end{lstlisting}
\end {document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Please add some text, other than just a title, to say what you question is.

Comment: you have `\s1shape` rather than `\slshape` and also `rgb` rather than `RGB` and also the blank line pointed out in an answer. If I correct all those, then it compiles for me.

Comment: @jfbu Sorry. I've only just seen your comment.

Comment: @Jubobs I accept half of a bitcoin as indemnity ;-)

Comment: @jfbu Ouch, that's steep!

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts (http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/49276/scorpius-xia and http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/49300/coolwind). The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems with your code.

1. You have a blank line in the argument of `\lstset`, which is not allowed.
2. There is a typo (`\s1shape` instead of `\slshape`) in the value passed to the `stringstyle` key.
3. You're misusing `\color`. Whether the optional argument is `rgb` or `RGB`, the mandatory argument should be a comma-separated or space-separated list of three values corresponding to Red, Blue, and Green. However, when the optional argument is `rgb`, each value must lie between 0 and 1, whereas, when the optional argument is `RGB`, each value must be an 8-bit integer (0 to 255).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper] {article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\setmainfont[BoldFont=黑体]{宋体}
%\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
%\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt minus 0.1pt
%\linespread{1.5}
\lstset{
numbers = left,
framexleftmargin=10mm,
frame=none,
backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{245,245,244}, % <--- use RGB (not rgb) if you use 8-bit color specifications
keywordstyle=\bf\color{blue},
identifierstyle=\bf,
numberstyle=\color[RGB]{0,192,192},
commentstyle=\it\color[RGB]{0,96,96},
stringstyle=\rmfamily\slshape\color[RGB]{128,0,0}, % <---- you had a `1' instead of an `l' in \slshape
% <--- do not leave blank lines in the argument of \lstset
showstringspaces=true
}
\begin {document}
\title{实验课}
\author{ coolwind}
\maketitle
\paragraph{}
你好，世界！

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("Hello world!\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j ++)
{
int tmp = i + j;
}
}
return 0;
}

\end{lstlisting}
\end {document}
```

Comment: @ScorpiusXia No problem. And [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of the blank line 19 allows this to compile for me!

Comment: are you sure? it doesn't for me.

Comment: Yeah! I don't know why...

Comment: you may have a `tex` engine detecting and correcting user mistakes `;-)`